# What is the best way to use django, haystack, angularjs and elasticsearch?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm building a search app using the stack of django, haystack and Elasticsearch. But I'd like to add angularjs. My question here is:

Which alternative is better for angularjs to receive data and manipulate it in the search app: 
1. Query directly the data in elasticsearch using the elasticsearch.js angular library
2. Or maybe take the data from haystack and start playing with it. So, haystack it is the only that can communicate with elasticsearch.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi I'm exploring similar options.  Wondering what you came up with?  Instead of Haystack I am just using elasticsearch-py

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on how heavy or light you want to keep things. Heavy might hurt a little at first, but could pay dividends down the road. If your goals are smaller or more short term (toy project or prototype), it might be better to have fewer moving parts.

If you go with the full blown:

ES <-> haystack <-> django <-> angular

then you get these sorts of wins:

- swap out the back end if you decide you don't like ES and want to use solr
- you can use haystack to abstract away from having to write gory raw queries
- if you *do* have to write gory raw queries, haystack will wrap them better than some javascript spaghetti
- django itself is awesome, if you are building something nontrivial it will be a *lot* easier to keep it clean than something that sits completely in the browser
- if you pull from other data sources, like a pordbms (plain old relational database management system ;) , django will again make that much less head explodey
- any mixing/mangling of disparate data sources will again be a lot easier and can stay hidden behind whatever routes your django server exposes
- since all the heavy lifting happens on the server side, your front end can stay just a front end with minimal logic. This will make it cleaner, easier to maintain and makes for a lighter js payload you have to return to clients.

So there's a lot to be said for this approach, but there's also potentially a LOT to set up. If you just need a front end driven by data in ES, then you can have a thick front end that queries ES directly. Some wins here:

- angular can make all the REST requests you need to make without too much fuss
- ES can receive all those REST requests
- They both natively use json so it's not like you have to deal with serialization/deserialization headaches (not that they'd be huge in python, but they're a nonissue here)
- BUT this can cut both ways, if you have really complicated queries that a client can't handle easily, you may find yourself doing really sordid manipulation of raw javascript objects, be warned
- fewer moving parts to configure, deploy, test, curse at, etc.
- when you start feeling growing pains with this stack, you can at least rip out the queries instead of having to write them all from scratch

I've worked on one stack that was solr/haystack/django/backbone and the separation of concerns and hiding/abstraction was pretty nice. I did not have to set up the whole stack from scratch, it was an existing project where I added/rewrote some sizable chunks.

I've also worked with an ES/node/angular stack where I set up the vast majority of it from scratch. The setup was... fast enough. The easy stuff was easy. When it got bigger, I felt like it was harder to impose enough discipline on the code to keep it really clean. So it's the sort of dangerous situation where, once the queries all seem to work, you back away slowly and hope no new feature requests come in (they always do, let's be honest). But again, if this is a little side project or you just want to try out some new stuff or you *want* it to be fast rather than robust, this is probably the way to start, then you can add in the other pieces as you start hitting walls.